# How do you organize data to specify a range for an hbar_stack that is not relative to 0? [Bokeh]

Tags: python, charts, visualization, bokeh

Here's an example of the code here:
https://imgur.com/a/mKPNP

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import GnBu3, OrRd3
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("stacked_split.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]

exports = {'fruits' : fruits,
           '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
           '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
           '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}
imports = {'fruits' : fruits,
           '2015'   : [-1, 0, -1, -3, -2, -1],
           '2016'   : [-2, -1, -3, -1, -2, -2],
           '2017'   : [-1, -2, -1, 0, -2, -2]}

p = figure(y_range=fruits, plot_height=250, x_range=(-16, 16), title="Fruit import/export, by year",
           toolbar_location=None)

p.hbar_stack(years, y='fruits', height=0.9, color=GnBu3, source=ColumnDataSource(exports),
             legend=["%s exports" % x for x in years])

p.hbar_stack(years, y='fruits', height=0.9, color=OrRd3, source=ColumnDataSource(imports),
             legend=["%s imports" % x for x in years])

p.y_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

I noticed that in this example of hbar_stack, the bars are rendered relative based on the data relative to 0.

How would I go about specifying a range for a bar that doesn't include 0? For example, if I wanted a bar to be between 5 and 10?

Comment: Please post the actual code, **NOT** an image of the code.

Comment: @James fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `hbar_stack` (and `vbar_stack`) always sum the relevant values starting from zero, without any kind of offset. Adding an offset seems like a potentially reasonable and straightforward thing to consider, so I'd suggest [making a GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to request the feature.

In the mean time, there's a few different ways that could work

- Use one call to `hbar_stack` but pre-bake the offset into your data. If your CDS columns are numpy arrays or pandas series this would be simple (add the offset to every column being stacked). Something like:

  ```
  for x in years:
      imports[year] += offset
      exports[year] += offset
  ```

  This won't work as-is with the code above because the columns are regular Python lists, but if you use arrays/series then adding the offset would be as done above.
- Use multiple calls to `hbar` and stack the bars yourself. The `hbar` glyph method accepts an agument `left` which happens to default to zero, but you can set it however you like to either a fixed value, or a CDS column. This will also be easier if the CDS columns are arrays or series:

  ```
  left = offset
  for x in years:
      right = left + exports[x]
      p.hbar(left=left, right=right)
      left = right

  right = offset
  for x in years:
      left = right - imports[x]
      p.hbar(left=left, right=right)
      right = left
  ```
- Use a [`CustomJSTransform`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/transforms.html#bokeh.models.transforms.CustomJSTransform) to do the stacking on the client side. Basically, you'd re-implement [`Stack`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/expressions/stack.coffee) but with an offset baked in

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to define the color range without start from zero.
I hope it helps you.

```
def painter(rate,max_value,min_value,palette):
        darkness = int(float(len(palette)-1) * float(rate - min_value) / float(max_value - min_value))
        return palette[darkness]
```